# IR frequency difference

Tags: arduino-leonardo, ir

I want to create a device that interfaces with the Light Strike Lasertag system using an Arduino Leonardo.

The Light Strike system uses not laser but regular infrared signals. According to a site that I found (http://www.meatandnetworking.com/projects/hacking-at-the-light-strike-laser-tag-game/) it uses 37.8 khz signals. I only found IR-receivers using 37.9 or 38 khz. Can I use them? How far can the modulation frequency differ?

Is there anything else I need to watch out for when creating an IR-interface?

Comment: That's more than close enough. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84327/universal-ir-receiver-for-tv-remotes. But note that the frequency being sent may vary from one gun to the next. So your may be different from the one that was tested in that article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use 37.9 or 38 kHz IR-receivers for 37.8 khz communication?

Yes you can, it should be close enough. (I am assuming you are talking about some kind of prebuilt receiver that just receives the IR data and transmits it via RS232 or something like that)

---

I'd suggest you'd use a phototransistor and a IR diode for the communication. You will have a lot more control over what frequencies you are operating on. Altho it might take a bit more work to program it, the end result will be exactly how you wish.